# Discord bot, task destroyed

Tags: python-3.x, bots, python-asyncio, discord, pokemon-go

I'm trying to make a bot for discord that send some coords to the chat channel, but when i run it after 2 minutes it stops giving the error the task was destroyed..
i'm not really good with python so if u want to explain i'll be glad to learn

```
import discord
import asyncio
import time
import datetime

from skiplagged import Skiplagged
client = discord.Client()
pf = Skiplagged()

def loginServer():
    client.login('token-discord')


async def pokeFinder():
    channel = discord.Object(id='channel_id')
    bounds = (
              (40.76356269219236, -73.98657795715332), # Lower left lat, lng
              (40.7854671345488, -73.95812508392333) # Upper right lat, lng
              ) # Central park, New York City
                # bounds = client.get_bounds_for_address('Central Park, NY')
    try:
            # Log in with a Google or Pokemon Trainer Club account
        #     print client.login_with_google('GOOGLE_EMAIL', 'PASSWORD')
        print(pf.login_with_pokemon_trainer('ptc_id', 'ptc_psw'))

            # Get specific Pokemon Go API endpoint
        print(pf.get_specific_api_endpoint())

            # Get profile
        print(pf.get_profile())

            # Find pokemon
            #if pf.num_pokemon_found > 0:
        for pokemon in pf.find_pokemon(bounds):
            ts = time.time()
            st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
            msg = "[" + st + "]" + str(pokemon)
            await client.send_message(channel, msg)
            print(msg)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        client.logout()
    asyncio.sleep(1)

async def my_background_task():
    channel = discord.Object(id='channel_id')
    msg1 = ""
    while not client.is_closed:
        if not client.is_logged_in:
            loginServer()
        else:
            await pokeFinder()

        await asyncio.sleep(5)
```

client.loop.create_task(my_background_task())
client.run('token-discord')

a guy said me that the problem is in the skiplagged.py because it uses request.
can you help me to convert the script from requests lib to aiohttp?

```
import base64
import json
import time
import traceback
import requests

from auth.google import Google
from auth.pokemon_trainer_club import PokemonTrainerClub
from utils.general import get_requests_session
from utils.pokemon import Pokemon
from time import localtime, strftime

def getMyTime(): return strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", localtime())

class Skiplagged():
    SKIPLAGGED_API = 'http://skiplagged.com/api/pokemon.php'
    GENERAL_API = 'https://pgorelease.nianticlabs.com/plfe/rpc'
    SPECIFIC_API = None
    PROFILE = None
    PROFILE_RAW = None

    _requests_skiplagged_session = None
    _requests_niantic_session = None

    _username = None
    _password = None
    _access_token = None
    _auth_provider = None

    def __init__(self):
        self._requests_skiplagged_session = get_requests_session('pokemongo-python')
        self._requests_niantic_session = get_requests_session('Niantic App')

    # Login

    def login_with_google(self, username, password):
        print(getMyTime(), "called login_with_google")     
        google_auth = Google()
        auth_provider = google_auth.get_auth_provider()
        access_token = google_auth.get_access_token(username, password)
        access_token = access_token

        return self._update_login(auth_provider, access_token, username, password)

    def login_with_pokemon_trainer(self, username, password):
        print(getMyTime(), "called login_with_pokemon_trainer") 
        ptc_auth = PokemonTrainerClub()
        auth_provider = ptc_auth.get_auth_provider()
        access_token = ptc_auth.get_access_token(username, password).decode()

        if not access_token or 'error' in access_token: raise Exception('failed to get access_token')

        return self._update_login(auth_provider, access_token, username, password)

    def _update_login(self, auth_provider, access_token, username, password):        
        if access_token:
            self._auth_provider = auth_provider
            self._access_token = str(access_token)
            self._username = username
            self._password = password

            return (self._auth_provider, self._access_token)

        return False

    def is_logged_in(self): return self._access_token is not None

    def _refresh_login(self):
        if not self.is_logged_in(): raise Exception('needs an existing log in')

        self.SPECIFIC_API = None
        self.PROFILE = None
        self.PROFILE_RAW = None

        if self.auth_provider == 'google': return self.login_with_google(self._username, self._password)
        elif self.auth_provider == 'ptc': return self.login_with_pokemon_trainer(self._username, self._password)

    def get_access_token(self): return self._access_token
    def get_auth_provider(self): return self._auth_provider

    # Calls

    def _call(self, endpoint, data):
        is_skiplagged_api = 'skiplagged' in endpoint
        requests_session = self._requests_skiplagged_session if is_skiplagged_api else self._requests_niantic_session

        while 1:
            try:
                if is_skiplagged_api:
                    time.sleep(1)
                    r = requests_session.post(endpoint, data, verify=False)
                    return r.json()
                else:
                    r = requests_session.post(endpoint, base64.b64decode(data), verify=False)
                    if b'Server Error' in r.content: raise Exception('invalid niantic server response')
                    return base64.b64encode(r.content)  
            except Exception:
                print("post exception", traceback.format_exc())
                time.sleep(1)

    def get_specific_api_endpoint(self):
        print(getMyTime(), "called get_specific_api_endpoint")
        if not self.is_logged_in(): raise Exception('need to log in first')

        response = self._call(self.SKIPLAGGED_API, {
                                                    'access_token': self.get_access_token(), 
                                                    'auth_provider': self.get_auth_provider()
                                                    })
        if not 'pdata' in response: raise Exception('failed to get pdata 1')
        d = response['pdata']
        response = self._call(self.GENERAL_API, response['pdata'])
        if not response: raise Exception('pdata api call failed')
        response = self._call(self.SKIPLAGGED_API, {
                                                    'access_token': self.get_access_token(),
                                                    'auth_provider': self.get_auth_provider(),
                                                    'pdata': response
                                                    })
        if not 'api_endpoint' in response or not response['api_endpoint']: raise Exception('failed to retrieve specific api endpoint')
        self.SPECIFIC_API = response['api_endpoint']
        return self.SPECIFIC_API

    def get_profile(self):
        print(getMyTime(), "called get_profile") 
        if not self.SPECIFIC_API: self.get_specific_api_endpoint()

        response = self._call(self.SKIPLAGGED_API, {
                                                    'access_token': self.get_access_token(), 
                                                    'auth_provider': self.get_auth_provider(),
                                                    'api_endpoint': self.SPECIFIC_API
                                                    })
        if not 'pdata' in response: raise Exception('failed to get pdata 1')

        response = self._call(self.SPECIFIC_API, response['pdata'])
        if not response: raise Exception('pdata api call failed')

        self.PROFILE_RAW = response

        response = self._call(self.SKIPLAGGED_API, {
                                                    'access_token': self.get_access_token(),
                                                    'auth_provider': self.get_auth_provider(),
                                                    'api_endpoint': self.SPECIFIC_API,
                                                    'pdata': self.PROFILE_RAW
                                                    })

        if not 'username' in response: raise Exception('failed to retrieve profile')
        self.PROFILE = response
        return self.PROFILE

    # Generates a realistic path to traverse the bounds and find spawned pokemon
    # Processed sequentially and with delay to minimize chance of getting account banned
    def find_pokemon(self, bounds, step_size=0.002):
        print(getMyTime(), "called find_pokemon") 
        if not self.PROFILE_RAW: self.get_profile()

        bounds = '%f,%f,%f,%f' % (bounds[0] + bounds[1])

        response = self._call(self.SKIPLAGGED_API, {
                                                    'access_token': self.get_access_token(), 
                                                    'auth_provider': self.get_auth_provider(),
                                                    'profile': self.PROFILE_RAW,
                                                    'bounds': bounds,
                                                    'step_size': step_size
                                                    })
        if not 'requests' in response: raise Exception('failed to get requests')

        for request in response['requests']:
            #print(getMyTime(), "moving player")
            pokemon_data = self._call(self.SPECIFIC_API, request['pdata'])
            response = self._call(self.SKIPLAGGED_API, {'pdata': pokemon_data})

            if 'pokemons' in response:
                num_pokemon_found = len(response['pokemons'])
                if num_pokemon_found > 0: print(getMyTime(), "found %d pokemon" % (num_pokemon_found))
                for pokemon in response['pokemons']: yield Pokemon(pokemon )
            else:
                num_pokemon_found =0

            time.sleep(.5)

    def get_bounds_for_address(self, address, offset=0.002):
        url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json'
        params = {'sensor': 'false', 'address': address}
        r = requests.get(url, params=params)
        results = r.json()['results']
        bounds = results[0]['geometry']['viewport']
        return (
                (bounds['southwest']['lat'] - offset, bounds['southwest']['lng'] - offset),
                (bounds['northeast']['lat'] + offset, bounds['northeast']['lng'] + offset),
                )
```

i need to use async with find_pokemon but i really don't how do that
thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, using `requests` within a discord.py bot (or any other asynchronous script) isn't a good idea, [the discord.py docs even have a section about this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#what-does-blocking-mean).

Basically you will need to replace code like this:

```
r = requests.get(url, params=params)
results = r.json()['results']
```

to:

```
async with aiohttp.get(url, params=params) as r:
    results = await r.json()['results']
```

But you can also use sessions just like in `requests`, you should take a look at the [aiohttp docs](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client.html#json-response-content) for this.
also don't forget to replace the imports at the top and install [aiohttp](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) through pip

`aiohttp` uses a lot of similar method names as `requests` so it's not that hard to switch from one to the other.